# Accessing Nested JSON in Ember Model

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to access a particular ID which is nested inside my model to make a belongsTo association. I have no trouble getting what I need in my template, but need `image_id` within my model. Below is my JSON and current model.

```
{
  content: {
      title: 'Title',
      header: 'Header',
      image_id: 1
  }
  slug: 'slug',
  title: 'Welcome'
}
```

Here is my current model...

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

const { attr } = DS;

export default DS.Model.extend({
  content: attr(),
  title: attr('string'),
});
```

Hope this makes sense!! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have similar use-cases (mostly a very variable settings paramter that is stored as json in db) and solved it via a custom transform:

```
// myapp/transforms/json.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

// Converts stringified json coming from database (usually in table-field 'settings') to a POJO
export default DS.Transform.extend({
    deserialize: function(serialized) {
        return JSON.parse(serialized);
    },
    serialize: function(deserialized) {
        return JSON.stringify(deserialized);
    }
});

//myapp/models/myModel.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    content: DS.attr('json')
});
```

Then in your template you should be able to do

```
{{model.content.image_id}}
```

Or in controller

```
let image_id = this.get('model.content.image_id');
```

or in model

```
this.get('content.image_id');
```

Comment: This is the way I would do this as well, but I would skip the json transform. If you don’t specify a specific option for content, content will automatically be deserialized into an object for you

Comment: @acorncom AH, you meen if I do a simple `content: DS.attr('json')` in model I wouldn't need the transform at all? Or do you meen to only skip the `JSON.parse(serialized)` in tranforms/json.js? (I ask this only to update my own knowlodge)

Comment: If you do a `content: DS.attr()` it should be the same as your `content: DS.attr('json')` and custom transform